# Forge Api - Search

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am showing multiple IFC files in my forge viewer. Till here everything is fine. What I am struggling with is that I want to find values of an attribute say for name from all the ifc files in the viewer with the values I also need to to that this value has come from which ifc file.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Welcome to SO. I don't know autodesk-forge, but is it a programming language or an api which is used by applications? Have you tried anything? Is there any source code example you can show us?

Answer (score 0):

Get the model reference and then call getProperties

```
for (const model of viewer.getVisibleModels()) {
  viewer.isolate(null, model);
}
Model.prototype.getProperties = function(dbId, onSuccessCallback, onErrorCallback) 
{...}
```

We have a multimodal refresher blog, please [refer here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/multi-model-refresher)